# How to merge overlapping string with unicode?

Tags: python, overlap

I am student of MCS and  learning python and stuck in one problem. I am trying to merge all overllaping strings.

I am using following algorithm but output is not as expected?

(1) find max overlap between all possible pairs.
(2) Store all the overlaps in dictionary with key as amount of overlap and values as start, stringa, stringb
(3) pick the maximum set of overlap and merge the string. I have implemnted my algorithm using following code but out does not produce expected output.

```
def overlap(a, b):

    overlaps = []

    for i in range(len(b)):
        for j in range(len(a)):
            if a.endswith(b[:i + 1], j):
                overlaps.append((i, j))

    return max(overlaps) if overlaps else (0, -1)


def get_merged_string(lst):
    overlaps = defaultdict(list)
    while len(lst) > 1:
          overlaps.clear()

          for a in lst:
              for b in lst:
                  if a == b:
                     continue

                  amount, start = overlap(a, b)
                  overlaps[amount].append((start, a, b))

          maximum = max(overlaps)

          if maximum == 0:
             break

          start, a, b = choice(overlaps[maximum])  # pick one among equals

          lst.remove(a)
          lst.remove(b)
          lst.append(a[:start] + b)
    str1 = ''.join(lst)
    return (urllib.parse.unquote_plus(urllib.parse.unquote_plus(str1)))
```

Input:

```
%23%21%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fpyth
n%2Fpython3%0A%0A%23%0A%23+
%0A%0A%23%0A%23+Python+fu
+Python+functio
unctions+start+
+start+with+def
th+def.++They+t
hey+take+parame
parameters%2C+whi
+which+are%0A%23+un
are%0A%23+un-typed%2C
n-typed%2C+as+oth
+as+other+varia
her+variables.%0A
es.%0A%0A%23+The+stri
string+at+the+s
the+start+of+th
rt+of+the+funct
function+is+for
n+is+for+docume
documentation.%0A
tation.%0Adef+prh
f+prhello%28%29%3A%0A++
%28%29%3A%0A++++%22Print+
+%22Print+hello%22%0A
hello%22%0A++++prin
+print%28%22Hello%2C+
llo%2C+World%21%22%29%0A%0A
World%21%22%29%0A%0Aprhel
%29%0A%0Aprhello%28%29%0A%0A%23
%28%29%0A%0A%23%0A%23%0Adef+prl
f+prlines%28str%2C+
ines%28str%2C+num%29%3A
num%29%3A%0A++++%22Prin
++++%22Print+num+
nt+num+lines+co
ines+consisting
onsisting+of+st
ing+of+str%2C+rep
+str%2C+repeating
epeating+str+on
r+once+more+on+
+on+each+line.%22
ine.%22%0A++++for+n
+for+n+in+range
in+range%280%2Cnum%29
num%29%3A%0A++++++++p
++++print%28str+%2A
%28str+%2A+%28n+%2B+1%29%29
+%28n+%2B+1%29%29%0A%0Aprli
+1%29%29%0A%0Aprlines%28%27
rlines%28%27z%27%2C+5%29%0A
%2C+5%29%0Aprint%28%29%0Apr
print%28%29%0Aprlines
rlines%28%27fred+%27%2C
red+%27%2C+4%29%0A
```

**My output:**

```
hello()

#
#
def prlines(str, num):
    "Print hello"
    print("Hello, World!")

prhellhe string at the start of the functions start with def.  They take parameters, which are
# un-typed, as other variables.

# The s#!/usr/bin/python3

#
# Python function is for documentation.
def prhello():
    "Print num lines consisting of str, repeating str once more on each line."
    for n in range(0,num):
        print(str * (n   1))

prlines('z', 5)
print()
prlines('fred ', 4)
```

**Expected Output:**   It is after merging overlapping string.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#
# Python functions start with def.  They take parameters, which are
# un-typed, as other variables.

# The string at the start of the function is for documentation.
def prhello():
    "Print hello"
    print("Hello, World!")

prhello()

#
#
def prlines(str, num):
    "Print num lines consisting of str, repeating str once more on each line."
    for n in range(0,num):
        print(str * (n + 1))

prlines('z', 5)
print()
prlines('fred ', 4)
```

Above issue is caused by ambiguity of overlapping. How can i fix such issue?

Comment: No response ... it seems like it is most difficult pblm ....

Comment: any other approach for merging overlapping strings could solve the issue.

Comment: what is `choice`? Is it `from random import choice`?